# Hyperlink Removal from emails Received

Tags: vba, outlook, hyperlink

I want to remove hyperlinks by VBA from  emails that is received. I found a [website](https://www.datanumen.com/blogs/2-methods-remove-hyperlinks-outlook-email/) which provided some code piece to remove hyperlinks.

I modified it to the codes below as I want to run it from the selected email of the inbox. i.e the email appears in the preview pane.

the code is finding the hyperlinks but can not delete them.
what is the problem?

EDIT: When I click forward button and the email is displayed in edit/prepare forward email, and run the code the hyperlinks are deleted.

EDIT2: with help of @niton, I found that the line below is required to be able to remove hyperlinks
'ActiveInspector.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "EditMessage"'

```
...
Set objSelection = objOL.ActiveExplorer.Selection
For Each objMsg In objSelection
    
    
    Set objInspector = objMsg.GetInspector
    x = objInspector.IsWordMail
    
    If (objInspector.IsWordMail) Then
    
    
       Set objDocument = objInspector.WordEditor
       Set objHyperlinks = objDocument.Hyperlinks
    
       On Error Resume Next
    
       If objHyperlinks.count > 0 Then
          strPrompt = "Are you sure to remove all the hyperlinks in this email?"
          nResponse = MsgBox(strPrompt, vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Remove All Hyperlinks")
          If nResponse = vbYes Then
             While objHyperlinks.count > 0
                   objHyperlinks(1).Delete
             Wend
             objMsg.Save
         End If
       End If
    End If.....
```

Comment: The example uses `ActiveInspector.CurrentItem`. Try `.Display`.

Comment: @niton, I tried with both of objInspector.Activate and objInspector.Display, none of them worked. objHyperlinks(1).Delete is not deleting actually. But when I forward the email manually and run the original code, objHyperlinks(1).Delete really delete the hyperlinks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found `objHyperlinks.count` to be zero.

With code adjusted to apply to open items, `objHyperlinks.count` remained unchanged. This construct deletes the first hyperlink in an infinite loop.

```vb
While objHyperlinks.count > 0
    objHyperlinks(1).Delete
Wend
```

In my setup, to run the code I have to display the selected items outside of the main code.
(Debugging can trigger whatever is needed to generate a non-zero `objHyperlinks.count`.)

```vb
Sub RemoveAllHyperlinksInSelection()

    ' If Debug.Print objHyperlinks.count gives zero,
    '  open all applicable items first.
    ' objMail.Display inside this sub is insufficient
    
    ' Sub OpenSelection() is a separate subroutine to display selected items
    
    Dim objItem As Object
    Dim objMail As mailItem
    
    Dim objInspector As Inspector
    
    Dim objDocument As Word.Document
    Dim objHyperlinks As Word.Hyperlinks
    Dim objHyperlink As Word.Hyperlink
    
    Dim strPrompt As String
    Dim nResponse As VbMsgBoxResult
    
    Dim objSelection As Selection
    
    Set objSelection = ActiveExplorer.Selection
        
    For Each objItem In objSelection
                
        If objItem.Class = olMail Then
            
            Set objMail = objItem
            Debug.Print objMail.subject
            
            Set objInspector = objMail.GetInspector
            Set objDocument = objInspector.WordEditor
            Set objHyperlinks = objDocument.Hyperlinks
            
            Debug.Print objHyperlinks.count
            
            objMail.Display

            ' The OP edited to add this line I suggested in a comment and indicated success.
            ' No impact on my results with this line.
            ActiveInspector.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "EditMessage"

            ' If you find this is zero run Sub OpenSelection() first
            Debug.Print objHyperlinks.count
            
            If objHyperlinks.count > 0 Then
                            
                strPrompt = "Are you sure to remove all the hyperlinks in this email?"
                nResponse = MsgBox(strPrompt, vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Remove All Hyperlinks")
                If nResponse = vbYes Then
          
                    Dim i As Long
                    For i = objHyperlinks.count To 1 Step -1
                    
                        objHyperlinks(i).Delete
                        
                        ' This remains unchanged
                        ' While Wend with objHyperlinks(1).Delete will remove
                        '  the first hyperlink in an infinite loop
                        Debug.Print objHyperlinks.count
                        
                    Next
                    
                    'objMail.Close olSave

                Else
                    objMail.Close olDiscard
                    
                End If
                
            Else
                objMail.Close olDiscard
                
            End If
            
        End If
        
    Next
    
End Sub


Sub OpenSelection()

    ' Run this before RemoveAllHyperlinksInSelection
    '  if you find hyperlinks are not found
    
    Dim objItem As Object
    Dim objSelection As Selection
    
    Set objSelection = ActiveExplorer.Selection
    
    For Each objItem In objSelection
        If objItem.Class = olMail Then
            objItem.Display
        End If
    Next
        
End Sub
```

Comment: Let me clarify that, I dont have any issue to get the count of all hyperlinks which are included in an email. The problem is with "objHyperlinks(i).Delete" if the email shown in a seperate window  for reading purposes, the objHyperlinks(i).Delete is not deleting actually. I guess the editing somehow disabled ,  I can track this from "objHyperlinks.count". as there is no change even after execution of objHyperlinks(i).Delete. However, as I said before, when I press forward button and editing becomes allowed, then "objHyperlinks(i).Delete" becomes functional and it deletes the hyperlinks.

Comment: However this time, objMail.Save creates drafts in the draft folder.

Comment: Is there any property which allows/prohibits changes in the original email.

Comment: I found edit mode had no impact. The reverse `For Next` instead of `While Wend` gave reliable results when mail was already open.

Comment: If you wish to try edit mode `objMail.Display` followed by `ActiveInspector.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "EditMessage"`

Comment: Thanks for directing me. the code of **ActiveInspector.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "EditMessage"** allowed to delete the hyperlinks as required. But now **objMail.Save** saves the email as draft. To see what will happen If I dont use **objMail.Save**, I removed it. I run the code and Closed the email window. A message window appeared which prompts me whether to save the emails for changes or not. Clicked OK, and the original email becomes without hyperlinks. Is there any other save method other than **objMail.Save**?

Comment: I do not reproduce your results. Edit the question to add a [mcve].

Comment: You are right. 'objMail.Save' is definetly working. and to be able to delete 'ActiveInspector.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "EditMessage"' is a must.

Answer (score 0):

In the loop where you iterate over selected items in Outlook the `objMsg` object is used:

```
For Each objMsg In objSelection
```

But to apply changes the `objMail` object is used instead.

```
objMail.Save
```

To save your changes you need to call the `Save` method on the item - in your case it is the `objMsg` instance.

Be aware, Outlook may not display changes immediately. Most probably you need to change the folder by setting the `CurrentFolder` property of the `Explorer` class to any other folder in Outlook and then return back to refresh the view on the reading pane, or just change the selection to make changes visible.

Comment: you are right that I missed to replace the objMail.Save to objMsg.Save. but the problem is different. When I debug the code and put a break point just at the beginning of the loop and use watches to see if the hyperlink count decrease. although, the line of objHyperlinks(1).Delete seems to be executed without any error, objHyperlinks.count never changes and loop continues forever.

Comment: Do you see hyperlinks removed in Outlook? Have you tried navigating to another folder and then switching back to the item where hyperlinks were removed?

Comment: You are right. Navigating to another email and select again the email whose hyperlinks removed worked.

Comment: Outlook doesn't reflect changes made programmatically. That is a known issue.